# VB.NET Azure deployment has no /bin but has a nuget package

Tags: vb.net, azure, nuget

I've just published (via GitHub) a VB.NET Azure Website that works fine on local machines but not on Azure:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'Newtonsoft' is not declared. It may
>   be inaccessible due to its protection level.

```
Dim category As Category = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Category)(json)
```

The Newtonsoft.Json package is installed via NuGet: Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.5. 
It's the only 3rd party dll in the project right now.

I used the Azure ftp access to browse to `/site/wwwroot/` and noticed that there is no `/bin` directory.

Now, my .gitignore excludes [Bb]in and [Oo]bj folders, but it's the same .gitignore I've used successfully with c# projects and always assumed that Azure just fetches the missing nuget dlls from `/packages`.

This is my first VB.NET > GitHub > Azure Websites deployment. What have I missed?

**edit:** I can confirm that if I upload `/Bin/Newtonsoft.Json.dll` via Azure ftp the site works. Or at least it will until it's re-imaged...

Comment: did you find solution. Facing same problem on private server

Comment: I can't remember how the problem was resolved. Perhaps I forgot to provide explicit consent for the NuGet Package Restore - see http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: I solved this problem. The problem was. Packages folder had newer version of Newtonsoft but csproj file had reference to the older version. Manually edited the file and the error was gone :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've not enable "NuGet Package Restore".

By doing so this creates a `.nuget` folder at the root of your solution and a `packages.config` file in the application that the build process in Azure will pick up and load the required references from.

Right click on the solution and it should be an option in there.

Comment: I'm not sure this is still the case: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html , but thanks anyway.

Comment: Wow, OK, looks like I need to do a bit of reading. thanks for the link!